# Como não mostrar tela de erro para Usuário - LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

Bom dia galera, como eu faço para não mostrar o erro **igual a imagem** para o Usuário?

**Essa imagem é só um exemplo**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qualquer no codigo que presente uma inconcistência  sempre tem que apresentar o ocorreu. O que você pode fazer e tratar os erros assim assim apresentando de forma coesa em uma tela amigavel  os possiveis erros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

basta editar o `.env` e setar `APP_DEBUG=false`

Comment: nossa perfeitooooooooooooooo... obrigado

Comment: marca concluído aki ^^

Comment: O meu nao fucnionou. php 7.4 Laravel 4.2

Comment: Deu certo pra mim, valeu!